# Next.js 13, Next Auth, Prisma: How to prevent a random (uninvited) user from registering if not permitted

Tags: authentication, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am creating an admin dashboard in Next.js (App dir) with next auth and prisma

As an admin, I want to be able to be able to invite people to sign up as an admin on my dashboard. I want them to access the sign up page and use their Google account to login, save their google account in my database, and have access to the dashboard. However, if a random person who was not invited accessed the sign up page, how can I prevent them from registering and saving their google account in my database?